# Running liquibase update from script in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, liquibase

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins pipeline which will run a liquibase update whenever something is pushed to the master branch. The liquibase runner plugin for Jenkins has a security risk and therefore, I can't install it and run liquibase updates from that.

My liquibase*  file (the bash script) is in my repository at the following path
`/repo/liquibase/liquibase/liquibase*`

I've set up the pipeline to run the following shell script. NOTE: I have the command set to `liquibase --help` for test purposes, but normally I'd want to run an update command.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/repo/liquibase
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/repo/liquibase/liquibase
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/repo/liquibase/liquibase/liquibase
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/repo/liquibase/liquibase/jre/bin
cd liquibase
ls -ltr
chmod 755 liquibase/liquibase
chmod 755 liquibase/jre/bin/java.exe
liquibase --help
```

The `liquibase --help` command runs fine from the directory path /repo/liquibase in git bash. However, when I run it from Jenkins, I get the following error.

> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Database_and_Repos/liquibase/liquibase/liquibase/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

My liquibase file looks like this and it is the last line in the file that is causing the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -n "${LIQUIBASE_HOME+x}" ]; then
  # echo "LIQUIBASE_HOME is not set."

  ## resolve links - $0 may be a symlink
  PRG="$0"
  while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
    if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
    else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
    fi
  done


  LIQUIBASE_HOME=`dirname "$PRG"`

  # make it fully qualified
  LIQUIBASE_HOME=`cd "$LIQUIBASE_HOME" && pwd`
  # echo "Liquibase Home: $LIQUIBASE_HOME"
fi


# build classpath from all jars in lib
if [ -f /usr/bin/cygpath ]; then
  CP=.
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/liquibase*.jar; do
    i=`cygpath --windows "$i"`
    CP="$CP;$i"
  done
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/lib/*.jar; do
    i=`cygpath --windows "$i"`
    CP="$CP;$i"
  done
else
  if [[ $(uname) = MINGW* ]]; then
    CP_SEPARATOR=";"
  else
    CP_SEPARATOR=":"
  fi
  CP=.
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/liquibase*.jar; do
    CP="$CP""$CP_SEPARATOR""$i"
  done
  CP="$CP""$CP_SEPARATOR""$LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib/"
  for i in "$LIQUIBASE_HOME"/lib/*.jar; do
    CP="$CP""$CP_SEPARATOR""$i"
  done
fi

if [ -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
  #JAVA_HOME not set, try to find a bundled version
  if [ -d "${LIQUIBASE_HOME}/jre" ]; then
    JAVA_HOME="$LIQUIBASE_HOME/jre"
  elif [ -d "${LIQUIBASE_HOME}/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/Home" ]; then
    JAVA_HOME="${LIQUIBASE_HOME}/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/Home"
  fi
fi

if [ -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
  JAVA_PATH="$(which java)"

  if [ -z "${JAVA_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Cannot find java in your path. Install java or use the JAVA_HOME environment variable"
  fi
else
    #Use path in JAVA_HOME
    JAVA_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"
fi

# add any JVM options here
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS-}"

"${JAVA_PATH}" -cp "$CP" $JAVA_OPTS liquibase.integration.commandline.Main ${1+"$@"}
```

Has anyone run into this problem with liquibase commands in Jenkins? I've been googling all day, but haven't found much similar to this exact issue. Any help in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

(We're updating the Liquibase Runner plugin. We have a release that is being reviewed for the security issues by the Jenkins team now.)

The error message seems to say that your "Execute shell" command in your changelog is not working correctly. Maybe the command is not installed, maybe it's calling a script that is not on your build machine.

One way to explore this to add an "echo" of the "Execute shell" command prior. Also, I'd pass --logLeve=DEBUG to Liquibase to get a better idea on the command it's trying to run.

Thanks for using Liquibase and Jenkins! I'll be talking about it here next month: https://www.cloudbees.com/devops-world/.

Comment: I actually figured it out! My JAVA_HOME path variable wasn't set on the box that the pipeline was running through.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [liquibase-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin) and just call the maven phase in the pipeline:

```
sh mvn resources:resources liquibase:update
```

As for me, it is the best decision. Follow the [official documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html)